# How do i use the androidyoutubeplayer lib to display player on template?

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular, youtubeplayer

I have successfully implemented com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.3 in the app.gradle but i dont know how to use the lib to add a YoutubePlayerView in  the html

I have tried to implement it programmatically but without any luck. My code:

app.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.3'
}
```

component.ts

```
declare const com: any;
const androidYtPlayer = com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;

pageLoaded(args:EventData){
    let youTubePlayerView = new androidYtPlayer(this);
    youTubePlayerView.videoId = `${this.id}`;
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    const stack = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("stack");
    stack.addChild(youTubePlayerView);

  }
```

component.html

```
<YoutubePlayerView id="youtube-player" videoId="id"></YoutubePlayerView>
```

I expected a youtube video to be shown but instead an error said :
com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView doesnt have enough parameters.
What should I do to use this native lib?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this before but finally moved to `nativescript-youtubeplayer`. It is very easy to use, you have to simply add that plugin using

```
tns plugin add nativescript-youtubeplayer
```

and import { YoutubePlayerModule } from 'nativescript-youtubeplayer/angular';

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    YoutubePlayerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and in your html

```
<YoutubePlayer id="player" apiKey="AIzaSyCDH3BGQZT2ebUfSE8D3I8NLqaCPu4FRh0" src="{{src}}" height="250" width="100%" backgroundColor="gray"></YoutubePlayer>
```

For further reading on this, you can refer [here](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-youtubeplayer).

Comment: I have also tried nativescript-youtubeplayer but after a couple of hours of use, it started breaking due to the API token limitations and got quite buggy. So this is not really an option for me. Should i continue with my efforts on the androidyoutubeplayer or move on? Could you suggest something different,please?

Comment: What do you mean by API token limitation? You have to register yourself and create your own token

Comment: This means that the token you create runs out because of daily limitations. The nativescript yputubeplayer comes up with a black screen saying "error in playing video". Plus only one video can be shown

Comment: Yes, That was the sample token.

Comment: I used the plugin way before i posted this comment with my own api key and it still had the same limitations. Any other suggestions in terms of libs to use?

Comment: why do I need a token only to embed videos ? ( which is done freely in web )